# Openlayers 3 changeChange view

Tags: javascript, openlayers-3

I'm beginner in Openlayers 3 and JavaScript. I would change the view of my map, but there is no addView() or removeView() function.

```js
var view_map = new ol.View({
    center: center,
    //projection: projection,
    zoom: 2,
    minZoom: 2,
    });

var view_sat = new ol.View({
    center: [0, 0],
    projection : projection,
    zoom: 3,
    minZoom: 2,
    maxZoom: 5
    });

var map = new ol.Map({
      target: 'map',
      layers: [layer_map],
      view: view_map,
      });
```

I want switch view_map with view_sat.

Answer (score 1):

I can't comment because I don't have enough reputation, but have you tried `map.setView(sat_view)`
(http://openlayers.org/en/v3.14.2/apidoc/ol.Map.html#setView)? There are also many examples at http://openlayers.org/en/v3.14.2/examples/, looking through them might help.